# How to avoid SQL Injection in Rails with Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ransack

How can we remove SQL blind injection in the following method?

```
def self.with_translation_value_of_language_id_eq(language_id)
    joins('LEFT JOIN BOTranslationValue on BOTranslationToken.id = BOTranslationValue.boTranslationTokenID '\
          "AND BOTranslationValue.languageID = #{language_id}")
      .select('BOTranslationToken.*, BOTranslationValue.value as current_language_value')
  end
```

I have tried `sanitize_sql_array` but it is not working.

And the following way as well

```
def self.with_translation_value_of_language_id_eq(language_id)
    joins('LEFT JOIN BOTranslationValue on BOTranslationToken.id = BOTranslationValue.boTranslationTokenID '\
          "AND BOTranslationValue.languageID = ?" language_id )
      .select('BOTranslationToken.*, BOTranslationValue.value as current_language_value')
  end
```

I tried multiple ways but none of it worked.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What is self class, means the model name?

Comment: What is the error you get while doing your second method? It seems alright (except from a missing comma before language_id)

Comment: What you you mean by "it doesn't work"? Is there an error? What does the error say? If there's no error, then what result are you getting? What result were you expecting?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, other than a missing comma. Alternatively as a *lazy* (!!) solution, you could have stuck with the original implementation but replaces `language_id` with `language_id.to_i` -- you can't SQL inject with an integer :)

Comment: It doesn't work means the value is not getting sanitized. Yeah I tried `language_id.to_i` but it is not working as well.

Comment: @AmolBudkhe What do you mean by "not getting sanitised"? What do you expect to happen? What are you seeing instead? Why do you think the code is still vulnerable, even when we force `language_id` to be an integer?

Comment: When we pass `language_id` with value `1 and NULL IS NULL`. When we do `language_id.to_i` it should fail or give an error. but it is not giving any error after doing `.to_i` and that value is been passed into the query.

Comment: Why should it "fail or give an error"? That wasn't part of your requirements. You asked to **prevent sql injections**, not "raise an error if someone provides dubious looking input that won't actually do any harm".

Comment: But if you like, then replace `language_id.to_i` with `Integer(language_id)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add comma `,`  after `?`, and you are not passing the correct where condition, Assuming that `BOTranslationValue` and `BOTranslationToken` are the correct table names, try the below query:

```
def self.with_translation_value_of_language_id_eq(language_id)
  joins('BOTranslationValue on BOTranslationToken.id = BOTranslationValue.boTranslationTokenID ')
 .where("BOTranslationValue.languageID = ?", language_id)
 .select('BOTranslationToken.*, BOTranslationValue.value as current_language_value')
end
```

Comment: Oops Sorry It was typo while adding the question. But I  tried with ','

Comment: can you try the above?

Comment: Yeah I tried the above way but it is vulnerable to Blind SQL injection.

Comment: no, its not vulnerable to SQL injection because we are passing the language_id as parameter. If we pass the `language_id` in the double quotes then its prone to SQL injection

Comment: `1 and NULL IS NULL ` we are trying to sanitise this value. Or when this value is being passed as `language_id` we are able fetch records. We tried to inject multiple things and was successful for fetching all the records.

Comment: Yes, thats why , its added as a parameter, you can create another function and return laguage id, can you try to pass 1 and null in language id and paste the logs

Comment: `SELECT BOTranslationToken.*, BOTranslationValue.value as current_language_value FROM BOTranslationToken Left join BOTranslationValue on BOTranslationToken.id = BOTranslationValue.boTranslationTokenID WHERE BOTranslationToken.type = 'cr' AND (BOTranslationValue.languageID = '1 and NULL IS NULL ') AND (BOTranslationToken.screenID = 1 AND BOTranslationToken.token LIKE '%John%')  ORDER BY BOTranslationToken.token ASC` This is mysql output

Comment: @AmolBudkhe That's not a vulnerability. If someone searches for the string: `"1 and NULL IS NULL"` then that's an odd thing to search for, but it's not hacking the database.

Comment: @TomLord that was just an example. We were successful for the sql injection and all the records were pulled out of that table.

Comment: @AmolBudkhe But your example is not a valid example. If you have a valid example of SQL injection that's still possible with the above code, then please do share it.

Comment: Agree with @TomLord, you should paste the example in which you were getting `SQL injection`